# With a while loop, how it is possible to output a number list with an ending dot for each number?

Tags: python, while-loop, printing

based on that code, I wish to output my result by ending each digit with a dot.

input:

```py
x = 0
while x<=5:
  print(x)
  x += 1
```

expected output:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
```

Comment: `print(f"{x}.")`

Comment: Are you trying to convert to floats?
`print(float(x))`

Comment: Just for fun: *print(*range(1, 6), '', sep='.\n', end='')*

Comment: @I'mahdi! I am not trying to convert to floats. Simply adding a dot. for aesthetic purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you start at `x = 1` and add a full stop to the string. Concatenating more letters or symbols to variables can be done with [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
# Start at 1
x = 1
while x <= 5:
    print(f'{x}.')
    x += 1
```

Alternatively, you could turn this into a one liner function:

```py
>>> def ordered(start, stop):
...     return '\n'.join(f'{x}.' for x in range(start, stop+1))
... 
>>> print(ordered(1, 5))
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
```

Answer (score 0):

Type casting can be used

```
x = 0
while x<=5:
    print(str(x)+".")
    x += 1
```

Comment: Did you try this and compare the output with the requirement?

Comment: I did try it! it works well, I also try an alternative offered by the community. thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, you can use the ` key to embed code :)

I believe what you want is:

```
x = 0
while x <= 5:
  print(str(x) + '.')
  x += 1
```

Let's break down the print statement:

We add the dot to `x`. We can't just add a string to an integer, so we first have to use the `str()` function to turn the numeric value of `x` into a string value: `str(x) + '.'`

Comment: i reccomend using fstrings, it's a faster method